# How does "any" type work with basic types like string?

Tags: apama

I am trying to use a switch clause to define what to do depending on the real type of a variable of type "any", my code is crashing. The code is the next:

```
handleResponse(any.parseType("string",respValuesRaw[type]), currEPIFace);
...
...
...
action handleResponse(any response, CurrentExtraParamsInteface currEPIFace){

switch(response){
    case string:
        {}
```

The error I am getting is: "ParseException - Error in ParseType() method: Unable to parse string: missing opening quote"

However, the `respValuesRaw` variable is a dictionary of type `<string,string>`

This is on Apama 10.1.

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this kind of parsing is not ment to be used with basic types, so I changed the way I call the handleResponse action:

```
handleResponse("string", currEPIFace);
```

Actually, any string value will fit.

Answer (score 3):

As per the doc for [any.parseType](http://www.apamacommunity.com/documents/10.3.0.2/apama_10.3.0.2_webhelp/ApamaDoc/any.html#parseType()), this is equivalent to calling type.parse, so this is equivalent to [string.parse](http://www.apamacommunity.com/documents/10.3.0.2/apama_10.3.0.2_webhelp/ApamaDoc/string.html#parse()), which states:

> The parse method takes a string in the form used for event files.
>   String arguments must be enclosed in double quotes. All escape
>   characters will be converted to the natural character.

If you just want to use the value of the entry of the dictionary, you probably want to just write:

```
handleResponse(respValuesRaw[type], currEPIFace);
```

The dictionary entry's value is a string, and it's legal to pass any type to an 'any' parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a basic type like string to `any` type is absolutely legal. Problem is somewhere else.

Since you're not passing a string in the form used for event files, it is giving error. Decoding the error message becomes really simple once you look at one example where `parseType` method is used. That gives some hint why does it really look for the *opening quote* in the argument.

---

Your problem simply put:

```
package com.apama.test;

event Evt{}
monitor Foo {
    action onload() {
        Evt e1;
        // handleResponse(any.parseType("string", "World!")); // #1 Invalid argument. Doesn't work
        handleResponse(any.parseType("com.apama.test.Evt", "com.apama.test.Evt()")); // #2
        handleResponse("World!"); // #3
    }
    action handleResponse(any response){
        log "Hello " + response.toString() ;
    }
}
```

prints:

```
com.apama.test.Foo [1] Hello any(com.apama.test.Evt,com.apama.test.Evt())
com.apama.test.Foo [1] Hello any(string,"World!")
```

while uncommenting `#1` gives error as shown below:

```
ParseException - Error in parseType() method: Unable to parse string: missing opening quote
```

Further, if you pass a properly-formed-but-a-non-existing-event to `parseType` method, it will throw an error stating that the type couldn't be found.

```
ParseException - Error in parseType() method: Unable to find type 'com.apama.test.Evt2'
```